# How to define a custom function that runs a command twice?

Tags: dired, motion

In dired mode, 'm trying to make a function that runs  `dired-next-line` twice and then bind to `SPC` so that I navigate files faster in dired mode.

I tried to add this in my `dired.el` file but it didn't work

```
(defun my-spcnxt-command()
  "Run `dired-next-line' twice."
  (interactive)
  (dired-next-line)
  (dired-next-line))
```

Comment: You are missing the argument (required) to `dired-next-line`. Add the argument and it works. Either add `1` to each call to `dired-next-line` or just use `(dired-next-line 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding this to my `dired.el` file

```
(defun my-spcnxt-command()
  "Run `dired-next-line' twice."
  (interactive)
  (next-line 2))
```

Comment: The function works but I don't know how to bind it to SPC

Comment: `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "SPC") 'my-spcnxt-command)`

Comment: You can accept your own answer, BTW.

Comment: @Drew, I added this to my init.el file and it worked. Thank you. My function is defined in dired.el. is that okay? Or should I define in my init.el file. I can't accept my answer it says "you can accept your answer in two days"

Comment: It doesn't matter where the function is defined that answers your question. You can accept your answer, or any other answer, in 2 days.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to place customizations in package files, `dired.el`in this case,as they may get overwritten when the packages are updated. Put them in your `init.el` instead.